# How can I view the source code for the readline module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, readline

I've scored the internet for almost an hour, but I can't find the actual github for readline, nor is it in `node_modules`. I hear that some are in binary, like events.js, but I found a repo for it. I'm trying to read through readline and learn how it works but I cannot find it. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Accept eol's answer, he beat me to it. Readline is built by node and thereby automatically included in your server. Only packages which is installed by `npm install <package_name>` is located in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the `libs`-directory on the official [github-repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node):

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/readline.js